# Dynamic layout in Yii

Tags: php, yii, sidebar

I have a Yii application and in the layout I have a static sidebar. I would like to change the content of the sidebar depending on the controller action, or the view. At the moment, in the `views/layouts/main.php` file, I have a sidebar defined as:

```
<div class="sidebar">hello!</div>
```

When the controller is `image` and the action is `test`, I would like to display this:

```
<div class="sidebar">Created at <? echo $image->created_at; ?></div>
```

The $image object is defined in the `image` controller and the `test` action.

In short, I would like to display a sidebar when the controller is `image` and the action is `test`, however, I would not like to have a different layout entirely. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: try to use `Yii::app()->controller->id` for controller name and `Yii::app()->controller->action->id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put a simple `if-else` check, using `getController()`, `getAction()` like this :

```
if(Yii::app()->getController()->getId()=='image' && Yii::app()->getController()->getAction()->getId()=='test'){
    echo '<div class="sidebar">Created at '.$this->image->created_at.'</div>'; 
}
else
    echo '<div class="sidebar">hello!</div>';
```

To access `$image` in a layout we need to make it a public property of the `image` controller itself, then in the action `test` where we initialize the `$image`, we will initialize the public `$image`, example:

```
 class ImageController extends Controller{
     public $image;
     ...
     public function actionTest(){
         $this->image=Example::model()->findByPk(1);// example
         ...
     }
 }
```

This will allow us to access image in the layout albeit using `$this->image->property`.

Also in the layout `$this` refers to the current controller, hence we can also use `$this->id` instead of `Yii::app()->getController()->getId()` to get the controller id(name which is *image* here) and `$this->action` instead of `Yii::app()->getController()->getAction()->getId()` to get the action id.

Comment: as llamerr has commented you can also use `Yii::app()->controller->id` etc

Comment: mashingan's solution below is also to be noticed, using the CClipWidget.

Answer (score 7):

This is work for clip. In your layout:

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <?php if(!empty($this->clips['sidebar'])) {
        echo $this->clips['sidebar'];
    } else { ?>
        hello
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Somewhere in your view:

```
<?php $this->beginClip('sidebar'); ?>
    Created at <? echo $image->created_at; ?>
<?php $this->endClip(); ?>
```